# Node.js script does not Exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Why does the following code not cause node to exit the process after running all 3 lines?

```
var monq = require('monq')
var client = monq('mongodb://remote.db.com:27017/mydB')
var queue = client.queue('users')
```

The script does exit if the 3rd line is not executed.

Comment: It looks like you've added a job to queue and it continues waiting to be told to execute the job.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait until async actions (processing the queue) will done, then, call `process.exit()` to end execution of script. See: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Answer (score -1):

It seems the underlying connection to Mongo doesn't get established until `client.queue('users')` is called. monq has a `client.close()` method that close its' db connection. With a few mods you can test this.

```
    var monq = require('monq')
    var client = monq('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydB')
    var queue;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // create the queue which establishes the connections
        queue = client.queue('users');
        setTimeout(function() {
            // close connection
            client.close();
        }, 5000)
    }, 5000);
```